# How to load a `zenity` List Dialog with space-embedded data from `ls`?

Tags: bash, zenity

I'm having problems loading a `zenity` List Dialog when the data contains spaces.

It is straight-forward when there are no spaces in the listed data,
but I don't know of a simple/standard method for space-embedded file names.

For some reason, the output of $(`ls -Q /tmp`) (Quoted output) still
splits the file-names at every space. The quotes and back-slashes in the
`ls | sed` output seem to be treated as a "finalized string" rather than
as "readable data lines" (like the first two data lines)...

I've managed to "work around the issue", but Self-Modifying code probably
isn't the best way to go! (even though it is fun! :)

---

Here is the method which does NOT work

```
zenlist="/tmp/zen list"; touch "$zenlist"
zenity --list --title='A single-column List' --width=600 --height=450 \
--column='Spaces are allowed within "q u o t e s"' \
"How much wood would a woodchuck chuck," \
"if a wooodchuck could chuck wood?" \
$(ls -Q -1 "$zenlist"* |sed 's/$/ \\/')
echo ""
# rm "$zenlist"  # Uncomment this line to delete the file
```

---

This method works, but there must be a "conventional" (better) way!?

```
zenlist="/tmp/zen list"
echo "zenity --list --title='A single-column List' --width=600 --height=450 \\" >"$zenlist"
echo "--column='Spaces are allowed within \"q u o t e s\"' \\"       >>"$zenlist"
echo "\"How much wood would a woodchuck chuck,\" \\"       >>"$zenlist"
echo "\"if a wooodchuck could chuck wood?\" \\" >>"$zenlist"
(ls -Q "$zenlist"* |sed 's/$/ \\/')   >>"$zenlist"
echo "" >>"$zenlist"
source "$zenlist"
# rm "$zenlist"  # Uncomment this line to delete the file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `ls`. It was never designed to be used in scripts. Besides, it's also pointless to use `ls` in scripts, because the shell can do the job much better, by simply using a glob, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns

```
zenlist="/tmp/zen list"; touch "$zenlist" "$zenlist"$'\neven with a newline'
zenity --list --title='A single-column List' --width=600 --height=450 \
       --column='Spaces are allowed within "q u o t e s"' \
       "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck," \
       "if a wooodchuck could chuck wood?" \
       "$zenlist"*
```

And for a general way to put list items with spaces and other chars into a "variable", use bash arrays.

```
# assign some items to start with
items=( "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck," "if a wooodchuck could chuck wood?" )

# append some items
items+=( "$zenlist"* )

zenity --list --title='A single-column List' --width=600 --height=450 \
       --column='Spaces are allowed within "q u o t e s"' "${items[@]}"
```

Comment: Wow!... I'm starting to see the true power of the shell... You have given very clear examples; and the link is also excellent... Thanks  ...

Comment: God, you're a lifesaver.

Answer (score 5):

You can pipe the list content into zenity, like

```
(echo "How much wood would a woodchuck chuck," ; \
 echo "if a wooodchuck could chuck wood?" ; \
 ls -Q -1 "$zenlist"* |sed 's/$/ \\/') \
| zenity --list --title='A single-column List' --width=600 --height=450 \
         --column='Spaces are allowed within "q u o t e s"'
```

Comment: Thanks Florian... That's certianly the way! ...and it only required: ls "$zenlist"* ... much better..

Comment: @Florian.. (1 month later).. Although your method got me rolling, geirha has now presented a pure bash "glob" method.. so there is actually no need fo 'ls' and 'sed'.